# page style get disturbed on ModalPopupExtender on click of button in a gridview in Update panel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a  multiple records in a Grid view inside an update panel, Grid-view has ImageButton , onclick of this button I am displaying a ModalPopupExtender to display details of selected row. Then I close the dialog using close button.

Everything works fine until I open and close the modelpopup 10 times , after that page styles gets disturbed and page start looking ugly. When I remove the update panel then everything works fine but I need update panel for smooth UI experience.

My code is below, please help me as soon as possible , I am stuck because of this. temporarily , I am handling this by dopostback on 10th time so that user doesn't experience refresh everytime.

aspx code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpDocuments" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="Content">
            <h1 class="HomePageHeading">Standard Operating Procedures, Guidelines, and Policies</h1>
            <div class="ClearFix MarginBottom30">
                <div class="SeriesInformation">
                    <h2>Series</h2>
                    <ol class="ValueList">
                        <li>1.000 - <span>Personnel Procedures</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>2.000 - <span>Veterinary Care/Laboratory Animal Medicine</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>3.000 - <span>Animal Husbandry/Facility Operations</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>4.000 - <span>Safety</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>5.000 - <span>Technical Procedures</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>6.000 - <span>Administration</span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div class="PolicyNumberAbbr">
                    <h2>SOP/Policy Number Abbreviations</h2>
                    <ol class="ValueList">
                        <li>P = <span>Policy</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>G = <span>Guidelines</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>B = <span>Bethesda</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>F = <span>Frederick</span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>


            <asp:Panel ID="SearchCriteria" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
                <div class="FilterWrap" style="clear: both;">
                    <fieldset class="FnlFieldSet">
                        <legend class="Clip">Filter SOP Listings</legend>

                        <ol class="InputFields">
                            <li>
                                <asp:Label Text="Filter by:" runat="server" ID="lblSortOrder" AssociatedControlID="ddlSortCriteria" />
                                <ol class="HorizontalInput">
                                    <li>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSortCriteria" runat="server" SelectMethod="Load_Filter"
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSortCriteria_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                                            AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>

                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCampus" Visible="false" runat="server" SelectMethod="Load_Campus" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="value" DataValueField="key">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="[Select]" Value="0" />
                                        </asp:DropDownList>

                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSeries" Visible="false" runat="server" SelectMethod="Load_Series" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="[Select]" Value="0" />
                                        </asp:DropDownList>

                                        <dms:WatermarkTextBox ID="wmTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="60" Columns="30" WatermarkText="Title" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="InputButtonWrapper HasIcon SearchIcon">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" runat="server" />
                                        </span>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" runat="server" />
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                        </ol>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            <dms:GridView ID="gvSOPDetails" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="Id"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectMethod="SopListingGrid_GetItem" Width="100%"
                OnRowCommand="gvSOPDetails_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvSOPDetails_RowDataBound"
                ItemType="Dms.Css.Ncif.Lasp.SopTraining.Biz.LaspSopTraining.Sop">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SOP/Policy#" SortExpression="Number">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Number %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkDeleteResponderIssueImage" NavigateUrl="<%# Item.MainFileAttachment==null?string.Empty:Item.MainFileAttachment.ResourceUrl %>" CssClass="FileDownloadLink" Target="_blank" Text='<%# Item.Title %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Revision Number" SortExpression="RevisionNumber">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRevisionNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.RevisionNumber %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>



                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Revision Date" SortExpression="RevisionDate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# string.Format("{0:d}", Item.RevisionDate)%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date" SortExpression="EffectiveDate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# string.Format("{0:d}", Item.EffectiveDate)%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campus" SortExpression="LocationId">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Dms.Framework.Extensions.EnumExtensions.Description(Item.LocationId) %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attachments" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnViewAttachment" runat="server" CommandName="ViewAttachment"
                                Enabled="true" CommandArgument='<%# Item.Id %>'
                                Text="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Media/Images/modal-open-icon.png" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No records match your search criteria.
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </dms:GridView>
        </div>

        <div>
            <%--    OnCancelScript="__doPostBack('Ok','')" is added to fix the issue when you open the model popup 10 times and on 11th time it mashed up the UI--%>
            <asp:Button ID="btnShowModelPopup" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="HideModelPopupButton" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedSOP" runat="server" />
            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeAttachments" runat="server"
                CancelControlID="imgBtnPopupClose"
                TargetControlID="btnShowModelPopup" PopupControlID="pnlAttachmentsForSelectedSOP"
                PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true"
                OnCancelScript="OnCloseButtonClientClick()"
                RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll"
                BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAttachmentsForSelectedSOP" Style="display: none" runat="server">
                <div>
                    <div class="PopupHeader">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPopupClose" CssClass="ModalCloseButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Media/Images/modal-close-icon.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="PopupBody">
                        <div class="PopupTitle">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <span>attachments</span>
                        </div>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSupportingAttachments" runat="server">
                            <ul>
                                <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvSupportingAttachments" DataKeyNames="Id" ItemType="Dms.Css.Ncif.Lasp.SopTraining.Biz.LaspSopTraining.Attachment"
                                    SelectMethod="LoadModelPopupAttachment">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li>
                                            <span>
                                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkDeleteResponderIssueImage" NavigateUrl="<%# Item.ResourceUrl %>" CssClass="FileDownloadLink" Target="_blank" Text='<%# Item.FileName %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:ListView>
                            </ul>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>



<asp:HiddenField ID="closeCount" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="0" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function OnCloseButtonClientClick() {
        if (count == 8) {
            //__doPostBack('Ok', '');
            count = 0;
        }
        else {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

---

```
protected void gvSOPDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ViewAttachment")
        {
            hfSelectedSOP.Value = (string)e.CommandArgument;
            mpeAttachments.TargetControlID = "btnShowModelPopup";
            lvSupportingAttachments.DataBind();
            mpeAttachments.Show();

  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got solution, It is only about moving code around update panel:
ASPX code:

```
            <dms:GridView ID="gvSOPDetails" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="Id"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectMethod="SopListingGrid_GetItem" Width="100%"
                OnRowCommand="gvSOPDetails_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvSOPDetails_RowDataBound"
                ItemType="Dms.Css.Ncif.Lasp.SopTraining.Biz.LaspSopTraining.Sop">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SOP/Policy#" SortExpression="Number">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Number %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attachments" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnViewAttachment" runat="server" CommandName="ViewAttachment"
                                Enabled="true" CommandArgument='<%# Item.Id %>'
                                Text="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Media/Images/modal-open-icon.png" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No records match your search criteria.
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </dms:GridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:Panel ID="pnlAttachmentsForSelectedSOP" Style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="PopupHeader">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPopupClose" CssClass="ModalCloseButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Media/Images/modal-close-icon.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="PopupBody">
            <div class="PopupTitle">
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <span>attachments</span>
            </div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAttachmentList" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSupportingAttachments" runat="server">
                        <ul>
                            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvSupportingAttachments" DataKeyNames="Id" ItemType="Dms.Css.Ncif.Lasp.SopTraining.Biz.LaspSopTraining.Attachment"
                                SelectMethod="LoadModelPopupAttachment">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>
                                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkDeleteResponderIssueImage" NavigateUrl="<%# Item.ResourceUrl %>" CssClass="FileDownloadLink" Target="_blank" Text='<%# Item.FileName %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </ul>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnShowModelPopup" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="HideModelPopupButton" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedSOP" runat="server" />
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeAttachments" runat="server"
    CancelControlID="imgBtnPopupClose"
    TargetControlID="btnShowModelPopup" PopupControlID="pnlAttachmentsForSelectedSOP"
    PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true"
    RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll"
    BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

ASPX.cs: code:

```
    protected void gvSOPDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ViewAttachment")
        {
            hfSelectedSOP.Value = (string)e.CommandArgument;
            mpeAttachments.TargetControlID = "btnShowModelPopup";
            lvSupportingAttachments.DataBind();
            upAttachmentList.Update();
    mpeAttachments.Show();              
  }
    }
```